# How to make text over an image adjust size according to browser size

Tags: html, css

I tried to put text over an image as a banner image, but whenever I resize the browser to check whether it is responsive, the text will go pass the boundaries of the banner image. How do I make it such that when the browser is resized the text will not clip out of the image and stays centered?

```css
.banner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 25%;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img class="banner-img" alt="banner image" src="images/banner.jpg">
  <div class="banner-text">Hello, Welcome To My Portfolio!
    <p>I'm Nicholas!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please update the image link first?

Comment: Maybe try using vw units instead of px?

Comment: how do you expect to keep text centered with: `position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 25%;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will place your text centered both horizontally and vertically. Also when you want a resposive website, refrain from using px. Use any relative unit instead like em or rem.

Maybe this link will help you understand better https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img class="banner-img" alt="banner image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605580556856-db8fae94b658?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
  <div class="banner-text">Hello, Welcome To My Portfolio!
    <p>I'm Nicholas!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't adjust the text size based on the browser size.

Comment: @Sean He didn't ask for that. He just didn't want the text to clip out of the image.

Comment: The title of the question is "How to make text over an image adjust size according to browser size"

Answer (score 0):

I posted a css code that in my knowledge could help you to solve the problem:

```css
.banner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
    min-height: 700px;
}

.banner-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 70px;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    .banner-text {
        font-size: 35px;
    }
}
```

I think these things must be considered:

> when you use "position:absolute" it is better to define a parent with "position:relative"

> for width of text elements it is better to use and change "font-size" not "width" property.

> for using in responsive method you must understand @media rules in css to change some properties in different screen sizes

> I also changed the top and left properties for centering the text, using "transform:translate" is necessary for perfect centering. you could change the values for your desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

you may use [`font-size:clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) and `grid` for centering without to mind about position:

> clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX) is resolved as max(MIN, min(VAL, MAX))

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: clamp(30px, 70px, 6vw);
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;/* for better visibility */
}

header h1 {
  font-size: inherit
}

header img,
header div {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/103/1200/800">
  <div>
    <h1>Hello, Welcome To My Portfolio!</h1>
    <p>I'm Nicholas!</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you should use a relative value for your font-size so when the screen size decreases your font-size also decreases. You should also add `position: relative` to the parent element of which in this case is `.banner` so when you add `position: absolute` to `.banner-text` it gets containered by the parent element.See below.

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2.4em;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .banner-text {
    font-size: 1.7em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img class="banner-img" alt="banner image" src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/582/542/non_2x/vector-abstract-template-black-frame-layout-metallic-red-light-on-dark-background-modern-luxury-futuristic-technology-concept.jpg">
  <div class="banner-text">Hello, Welcome To My Portfolio!
    <p>I'm Nicholas!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also added a media query for it to adjust its font-size on smaller screens.